# where to find CC for solaris 8?

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

I need to compile openssl on solaris 8 sparc, the compilation is broke due to missing 'cc' compiler.
I wasn't able to find any working link for Sun cc,
all I found are broken links to Sun Solaris Studio.

[update]

I found something looks like contains Solaris Studio 11, but I didn't use it I managed to find
something locally.

url: https://updates.oracle.com/download/12685437.html

Comment: Oracle Solaris Studio is the current name for the Sun cc compilers, but Solaris 8 is a very old release and is about to end support life in a few months and software for it is no longer being made available for download other than via an Oracle support contract.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specifically have a requirement for Sun Studio, tcgware maintains a catalog of pre-compiled Solaris packages, including for Solaris 8 Sparc.

http://jupiterrise.com/tgcware/tgcware.solaris.html

You can get gcc (and dependencies) there.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative site for downloading the latest pre-compiled version of gcc for Solaris is http://unixpackages.com, however, while it has the latest packages, it is subscription based (USD 20 for 10 packages). gcc also has 4 or 5 dependencies/pre-requisite packages to install, so keep that in mind when choosing your subscription plan.

You can also get pre-compiled versions of openssl (and dependencies) from there and avoid the need to compile your own, but if you expect to need to compile other packages in the future, then getting gcc is probably the better strategy.